# Know when a hyperlink within a Text Field is clicked?

Tags: flash, actionscript, textfield, hyperlink

In Flash, is there any event when the user clicks a hyperlink in a TextField?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is: TextEvent.LINK, but it only works with links prepended with "event:".

```
tf.htmlText = "<a href=\"event:http://www.example.com\">Example</a><br>";
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html

If you're pulling in external data not using "event:" syntax, you could probably easily write a quick RegExp to add it in.

Answer (score 1):

It seems possible, check out the [reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#event:link).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the TextField event "link" - it is dispatched when a user clicks a hyperlink within the TextField.

A great example is supplied in the [Adobe site](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#event:link).

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that replaces hrefs with "event:" prefixes (as suggested by geraldalewis above):

```
public static function hrefEvents(s:String):String {
    var hrefRegex:RegExp = /href="/gm;
    var output:String = s.replace(hrefRegex, "href=\"event:");
    var dupe:RegExp = /event:event:/gm;
    output = output.replace(dupe, "event:");
    return output;
}
```

Note that I make sure to undo the replace for hrefs that already have "event:" in them. (I could have used a negative look-ahead assertion in the regex, but I was lazy.)